# Retrieving cached definitions from subkernel into the main kernel during parallelization

Tags: parallelization

I am trying to do a computation that takes a lot of CPU time and it is quite computationally intensive. I want to make it Parallel instead of serial to compute the results faster.

Things I tried:

`Step 1`. I launched 2 sub kernels on which I would like to do the computation. The `$DistributedContexts` is set to `None`. This is because of the vast number of functions and definitions that need to be distributed. Instead, I load all the definitions and rules into a script `file.m` and evaluate the script across all the sub-kernels and in the main kernel as well.

`Step 2` I define a list `CachedQntity` as a list of inputs to be evaluated for the function `DerivCache` that has been defined in the `file.m` and is present in all kernels. In reality, the list is very large and I have presented only a subset here.

```
DerivCache[stf_[inds___], derivorder_, pnorder_] := 
 DerivCache[stf[inds], derivorder, pnorder] = 
  Evaluate[PNExpUntilFixed[DerivCacheHelper[stf[inds], derivorder, pnorder],pnorder]]
```

This is the function that is supposed to be evaluated on the `CachedQntity` list. It tries to calculate the derivatives of a tensor(`stf[inds]`) at some fixed post-Newtonian order. `pnorder` is a fraction or integer, and `derivorder` is a whole number representing the number of derivatives. Also, it caches the expression obtained after calculating the derivative.

```
LaunchKernels[2];
$DistributedContexts = None;
Get["/directory/file.m"];
ParallelEvaluate[Get["/directory/file.m"]];

CachedQntity := {{\[ScriptCapitalI][], 5, 8}, {\[ScriptCapitalX][], 3,4}};
STFCacheHelper := ParallelMap[DerivCache @@ # &, CachedQntity];

DumpSave["/directory/file.mx", {STFCacheHelper, STFDerivCache}];
```

`Moving ahead:`
The problem that I am having is the following. Consider that I have some number of kernel (ex -3) and the length of the list `CachedQntity` is 12. The `ParallelMap` distributes the list over the kernels to be evaluated on the function `DerivCache` and gives the result in a list.

But I know that when `DerivCache` tries to compute something it also caches that result into its definition. I would like to retrieve those cached definitions from each sub-kernel and combine them into a single definition of `DerivCache` with all the cached expressions in the main kernel. Then the last step is to save that definition as a final result into a .mx file.

How to achieve this? I don't know how to retrieve definitions from the sub kernels and get them into the main kernel. Is there another way to achieve the intended result?